# I am getting error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: wordpress

My website is showing Parse error, when I tried to disable the specific plugin, the situation gets worse and starts showing error in another jetpack plugin, if I disable all plugins, the error shows in some different file. please help, my site is down for two days.

Tried disabling plugin/s, reinstalling the plugin, deleting the errror code line

```
/**
     * Define Mega Menu constants
     *
     * @since 1.0
     */
    private function define_constants() {
        define( 'MEGAMENU_VERSION',    $this->version );
        define( 'MEGAMENU_BASE_URL',   trailingslashit( plugins_url( 'megamenu' ) ) );
        define( 'MEGAMENU_PATH',       plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
    }

            // populate grid sub menus
            if ( $item->depth === 0 && $item->megamenu_settings['type'] == 'grid' || ( $item->depth === 1 && $item->parent_submenu_type == 'tabbed' && $item->megamenu_settings['type'] == 'grid') ) {

                $saved_grid = $widget_manager->get_grid_widgets_and_menu_items_for_menu_id( $item->ID, $args->menu->term_id, $items );

                $next_order = $this->menu_order_of_next_sibling( $item->ID, $item->menu_item_parent, $items) - 999;

                foreach ( $saved_grid as $row => $row_data ) {

                    $rolling_dummy_id++;
                    $next_order++;
```

Error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home/u912283588/domains/meersgavhb.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/megamenu/megamenu.php on line 309
The site is experiencing technical difficulties.
```

Comment: Please, can anyone help? My site is down for three days now. I will be really grateful!

Comment: what is the plugin link? Also if disabling the plugin causes the error to show in some other file, you might need to ask someone to look in your files to identify the exact issue.

Comment: @FahamShaikh Thankfully, Wordpress sent a recovery link through which I deactivated and deleted the plugin which brought the site to normal. Apparently this is a new feature they added in Wordpress 5.2. 
Thank you for your concern though!

Comment: Happy for you!!